# Golang abstraction in handler to avoid code duplication

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I am trying to implement abstraction in golang
I am using `gorm` orm library and `gin` framework

> Base Class

```
type Base struct {
  Context *gin.Context // Passing gin request
}

func (b *Base ) Add() {
   err := b.Context.BindJSON(b)
   if err != nil {
     // handling error here
   }
   gorm.db.Create(b) // Here I am adding base data to database
}
```

> Child Class

```
type Shopper struct { 
   Base  // Embedding Base struct
   Name string,
   Address string,
   ContactNo int
}
```

> Handler

```
 func handler (c *gin.Context) {
  s := new(Shopper)
  s.Context = c
  s.Add()  // Here I am expecting Add() method should bind JSON to shopper struct
           // entry to database using gorm
 }
```

`Add()` method is not taking any property which `shopper` struct has.

Here I just want to avoid `code duplication` in each `handler` which 
just takes json from request body and add to respective `database` using `gorm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't because [Go does not have inheritance](https://golang.org/doc/faq#types).

Let me repeat: Go does not have inheritance, so please unlearn this "base" and "child" stuff when working with Go.

The reason your code does not work is that while the method set of
an embedded type is indeed "lifted" and merged into the method set
of the type which embeds it, when any of such methods is called
*its receiver is the value of the embedded type* and not the
value of the enclosing type.

IOW your `Add()` method always receives values of type `Base`

If the enclosing type has a method which has the same name
as a method of the embedded type, and you call such method
on a value of the enclosing type, the method of the enclosing
type will be called.
So there's no overloading but there's "overriding" if you want.

What I'd do in your situation is stop thinking in OOP
and wrote a function rather than a method (untested):

```
func add(any interface{}, ctx *gin.Context) {
   err := ctx.BindJSON(any)
   if err != nil {
     // handling error here
   }
   gorm.db.Create(any) // Here I am adding base data to database
}
```

Then in your handler:

```
func handler (c *gin.Context) {
  s := new(Shopper)
  s.Context = c
  add(s, c)
}
```